# 404 File not found The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Trying to host my react app in github pages and I keep getting this error.
My repository : https://github.com/NikhilSethuram/nstPortfolio

I tried the normal approach ,
added homepage to package.json , added the extra scripts, npm build, npm deploy - it says published when i access my homepage i get the 404 error